# making a "load more" button in uitableviewcell?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios4

hey, 
Could any one guide me through this I have around 15 entries in table I would like another 15 to come up with the load more in last UITableViewCell. could anyone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Load More" in UITableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410257/) or [How to implement "Load 25 More"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801069/) or [Mail app load more messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396464/) or [Load more records in iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965919/) or [Add load more option to table view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898399/) among [others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iphone+load+more)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

to show an extra row in the tableview, in

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return dataRows+1;
    }
```

In

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 

        //after setting tableviewcell

        if(indexPath.row==dataRows){

        cell.textLabel.text=@"Load More Rows";
        }
    }
```

In

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

    if(indexPath.row==dataRows){
    //there you can write code to get next rows
    }
 }
```

You need to update the numberOfRows variable according to the displayed rows.

**Edit:** After fetching the extra entries, you can add them to the existing entries array using the following method. Your original array should be a `NSMutableArray` to use this method.

`[originalEntriesArray addObjectsFromArray:extraEntriesArray];`

Comment: @SriPriya, Add this line `numberOfRows = [yourEntriesArray count] + 1;` to make it more clear.

Comment: so do i add +1 to return for - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section ?

Comment: @SriPriya, I've edited your answer to add more context. I hope you'd not mind. :)

Comment: @user655995: yes, it says, if dataRows are 15, we set numberOfRows to 16 to show an extra row displaying "Load More Rows"

Comment: Any idea how to do it using custom cell?

Comment: YO! Index becomes out of range. What gives, brodies?

Answer (score 8):

I wrote an example project that does just this. Download it from GitHub https://github.com/Abizern/PartialTable

Comment: I like the part of updating the tableView using `beginUpdate` and `endUpdate`

Answer (score 4):

I wrote something that might be helpful : https://github.com/nmondollot/NMPaginator

It encapsulates pagination, and works with pretty much any webservice using page and per_page parameters. It also features a UITableView with automatic fetching of next results as you scroll down.

Answer (score 1):

hope this helps

I took an Mutable array and an integer variable and set the total count of the array to the integer variable

```
arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Radix",@"Riki", nil];
dataRows = [arr count];
```

and then i set the number of rows in the sections as per the integer variable in the datasource method of the table

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return dataRows+1;
}
```

because you wanted an extra cell at the end.

Now its time to set the text of the table cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell...

//setting the text of the cell as per Mutable array
if (indexPath.row < [arr count]) {

    cell.textLabel.text = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

 //setting the text of the extra cell

if (indexPath.row == dataRows) {
    cell.textLabel.text = @"more cells";
}     
return cell;
```

}

now on the hit of the more cells cell you want extra cells right so just add your code inside the

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method, means you have to do something like this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row == dataRows)
    {
        //code for exra cells please
    }
}
```

Run your app to check this code out.