# Add activity indicator at bottom of UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have `UITableview` with pagination like first  will get 20 objects from server and will populate in `UITableView` then when it reaches last row need to make another service call to get next 20 objects.

My problem is I need to add activity indicator at bottom of my table and should say "Loading", User can scroll to up to view current objects but should not scroll down.

Is there any custom control?
Is there any best way to achieve it?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [making a "load more" button in uitableviewcell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159844/making-a-load-more-button-in-uitableviewcell)

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using a UIActivityIndicatorView with appropriate frames set? There are also custom controls like MBProgressHUD, but your application seems straightforward enough.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Let's Try TableView Footer View to show activity indicator.

For example :

Declare `UIView * footerView;` in .h file

Add Following methods in .m file

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     [self initFooterView];
 }

 -(void)initFooterView
 {
    footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 40.0)];

    UIActivityIndicatorView * actInd = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

    actInd.tag = 10;

    actInd.frame = CGRectMake(150.0, 5.0, 20.0, 20.0);

    actInd.hidesWhenStopped = YES;

    [footerView addSubview:actInd];

    actInd = nil;
 }

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
     BOOL endOfTable = (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= ((self.contentArray.count * 40) - scrollView.frame.size.height)); // Here 40 is row height

    if (self.hasMoreData && endOfTable && !self.isLoading && !scrollView.dragging && !scrollView.decelerating)
   {
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerView;

        [(UIActivityIndicatorView *)[footerView viewWithTag:10] startAnimating];
   }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: thank you friend let me try @Natarajan

Comment: This is the best solution I've seen so far for this problem. Good for you for adding useful answers instead of winey criticism like the people who down pointed this question.

Answer (score 2):

check out this open source project.its may help you...

https://github.com/dkSolutions/DKPaginatedTableView