# Want to fire scrollViewDidScroll before go to bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm using collection view to view my rss feed data. I am using `-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` to detect the view go to bottom & load more rss feeds.
But I want call the `scrollViewDidScroll` method not in the bottom of my view, but just 2 or 3 index items before the bottom. How can I edit my `scrollViewDidScroll` method to perform this.

Comment: Please refer this link to add load more indicator at bottom of your view.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22474081/add-activity-indicator-at-bottom-of-uitableview/22474333#22474333

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView
{
    CGPoint offset = aScrollView.contentOffset;
    CGRect bounds = aScrollView.bounds;
    CGSize size = aScrollView.contentSize;
    UIEdgeInsets inset = aScrollView.contentInset;
    float y = offset.y + bounds.size.height - inset.bottom;
    float h = size.height;

    float reload_distance = -2 * [your item height];
    if(y > h + reload_distance) {
        [self.delegate loadMoreDataHere];
    }
}
```

Comment: Are not there any way to fire [self.delegate loadMoreDataHere]; just one time?? From the above code [self.delegate loadMoreDataHere]; fires hundreds of times when I scroll below the level.

Comment: You could add an additional check to the if statement for that. Something along the lines of if your data model count and based on that call the method or skip it.