# Dynamically loading UITableView with new rows

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, lazy-loading

I have searched SO and have yet to come to a definitive answer.

I have an app similar to Facebook and Instagram, where once you get to the bottom of the `UITableView` it calls a web service and loads another 25 rows of data.

The problem I facing is that on loading the new 25 pieces, I am calling `reloadData` and this causes unpleasant UI flashing.

What's the proper way of dynamically adding the new data to the UITableView as they scroll without the flashing (aka not calling `reloadData`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you add the new row items to your data source you need to use `[tableView beginUpdates];` and `[tableView endUpdates];` not `reloadData`.

```
NSMutableArray *indexPathsToAdd = [NSMutableArray new];

for (Object *object in currentObjects)
{
    if (![newObjects containsObject:object]) {
        int row = [currentObjects indexOfObject:object];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];
        [indexPathsToAdd addObject:indexPath];
    }
}

[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToAdd withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: that did it. Thank you! The flashing is resolved, but I am experiencing some jitter. If i scroll too fast it looks like it's inserting rows above and causes the screen to jitter. It looks like it hasn't finished inserting all the rows yet and causing the screen to shift.

Comment: You could try loading more rows before the user gets to the end of the current dataset. Another option would be to show a loading wheel when the user reaches the end so you can't scroll super fast, I'm pretty sure this i show facebook does it.

Comment: I like the loading wheel idea. Do you happen to know how it works?

Comment: It's fairly easy. Here is a link to get you going: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22474081/add-activity-indicator-at-bottom-of-uitableview